# Need Vertical Scrollbar in idangerous vertical swiper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using idangerous vertical swiper of two slides in a mobile app using jquery mobile. I need a vertical scroll bar in second slide as I have grid in it, but both as the slide height is fixed I am unable to achieve it. I have a thought that swiper event and scrolling event will be collided. I have tried in lot of ways but couldn't break this.

Thanks,
E. Ramesh Babu

Comment: I have used this before, please create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and put the code in there. Then we can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

So are you looking for something like this?

### CSS:

```
.swiper-slide:nth-child(2) {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

It should be a simple as that.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/Xuz4z/22/)

And here is making it vertical

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/Xuz4z/23/)

Comment: Hi Rubby,

I know this could be one option. But it works only for Desktop as we have a scroll option in it whereas for a mobile application as i mentioned in my question the swipe and scroll events are same so they are colliding which is resulting in partial scrolling and partial swiping.

Comment: @erameshbab Ruddy* and how aout putting a `onClick` event on the slider? So you have to click it once to get it to let you scroll?

Comment: Ruddy, I think its a good idea. But for a clear understanding can you make it as a demo in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

on mobile devices, you should use

> e.stopPropagation();

on the element you want to scroll on touchstart event